# iPhone UIGestures

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I used

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIView* view = gestureRecognizer.view;
    CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:view];
}
```

But this gave me an error at `CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:view];`
Why???

Comment: ?What does the error message say?

Comment: [UITapGestureRecognizer locationInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x193490
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UITapGestureRecognizer locationInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x193490'

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an error in your code but, the error indicates that the instance of gestureRecognizer being passed is not a UITapGestureRecognizer.  Put a breakpoint on the failing line and get type information gestureRecognizer.

Aside: Make sure you are using SDK 4.0 or greater from iPhone.  Gesture recognizers came in at 3.2 for iPad and 4.0 for iPhone.)  I suspect you are okay though since I think you would get an error earlier if you weren't using the right SDK.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
```

or alternatively rename the UIView *view.. like so:

```
UIView* gesturevView = gestureRecognizer.view; 
CGPoint loc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gesturevView];
```

Comment: i used this also But same error is given.I created an universal application on ipad i used UIGesture class perfectly but on iphone its give me error

Comment: What OS version are you running on? UIGestureRecognizers shouldn't be used before 4.0.